# How serious is: spi-nor spi0.0: BFPT parsing failed. Please consider using SPI_NOR_SKIP_SFDP when declaring the flash on bootup?

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

Just updated my Lenovo Yoga X-13 Gen 2 From Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.10 a day or two ago.

Today, I had to re-install the Ubuntu O/S today, because :
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grub64.efi: Not Found

It would then boot into Windows 11.

After the Ubuntu re-install, it boots into Ubuntu, but I get this screen full of complaints before the login screen.

```
0.736755] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size o is invalid

0.738537] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid 

1.280251] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280267] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280279] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280292] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280303] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280315] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280327] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280340] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280351] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280363] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280374] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280387] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280399] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280411] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280421] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280434] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280446] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280459] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280469] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280481] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280493] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280505] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280517] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280529] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280541] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 

1.280551] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280563) blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280701] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280710] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280750] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280781] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280823) blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

1.280850] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)

/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 221517/3670016 files, 3865497/14674944 blocks

4.457885] spi-nor spi0.0: BFPT parsing failed. Please consider using SPI_NOR_SKIP_SFDP when declaring the flash
```

Is it safe to ignore these messages, or is it a sign that I will continue to have problems with grub disappearing?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: I installed 22.04 a week or so ago, and get a popup that says "problem Detected. Do you want to report?" I always click yes, but it happens every time I boot. I looked at dmesg, and found "BFPT parsing failed. Please consider using SPI_NOR_SKIP_SFDP when declaring the flash." I don't know what this means or how I could change the boot process to affect it. I've updated the installation and grub several times for other reasons, yet it persists. I don't know if it's harmful or not.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: In my case, this happened just now, after I wanted to wake up the laptop after a suspension. The system didn't take me to the login page and got stuck with this error.